# MYSQL : optimize request with query (1,n relation)

Tags: mysql, optimization, request

Here is my concern : I have a request concerning two tables, in a 1,n relation that I would like to optimize.
Table 1 is Planning table, with lines that represent a dated event for a patient.
Table 2 is a patient-care table, with begin and ending dates.

```
**Table 1 : Planning**
Id
Begin
End
Patient_care_id

**Table 2 : Patient care**
Id
id_patient_care
Id patient
Begin 
End
```

Each line of table 1 must be covered by at least one of the table 2 line by dates, but it can be covered by several line2 lines.
I cannnot link a t1 line to an unique id in t2.

My request finds lines en Table 1 that **are not** covered by Table 2 dates, linking with table1.patient_care_id = table 2.patient_care_id.
To proceed, I make a subrequest :

```
select id 
from table1
where id not in
(
    select table1.id 
    from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.patient_care_id = t2.id
    where t1.begin >= t2.begin and t1.end <= t2.end
 )
```

Note : interventions are on a single day, t2 are on a plan days (befin at 00:00:00 and end at 23:59:59) cannot cover several days, that's why I use t1.begin for comparison... I could use t1.end)

Example :

```
T1-Planning
Id : 1
Patient_care_id : Amapa
Begin : 2020-01-01 14:00:00
End : 2020-01-01 16:00:00

Id : 2
Patient_care_id : Amapa
Begin : 2020-01-02 14:00:00
End : 2020-01-02 16:00:00


T2: Patient care
Id : 1
Patient_care : Amapa
begin : 2020-01-02 00:00:00
end : 2020-01-31 23:59:59
```

here, I want the request to send my Id 1 from t1 (that is not covered by t2 dates), and not Id 2 from T1 (that is covered by T2 dates).

Is there a way to optimize this request without making a subrequest ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add sample input along with expected output please ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rcgiw5

Comment: Ok I do it now.

Comment: @jska13 if you are getting duplicated rows just put on the end group by table1.id

Comment: @jska13 also, you can do something like this https://prnt.sc/rcgl3b

Comment: if you want to get records which are associated with next table use left or right joins. In case of duplication same data use distinct() method (function) on identifier column. But using methods on columns will reduce performance of query. To see insights of your select query use EXPLAIN before select keyword in query.

Comment: @Zeljka Thank you, since i want t1 lines NOT covered I have modified the request you gave, it works and seems to be faster than my subrequest version.

Comment: @jska13 then just change condition like this https://prnt.sc/rcgtg3

Comment: @ZeljkaYes i had already done this, it works and seems to be faster. Thank you.

Comment: @sashiksu OK thank you, indeed  I want to faster the query, the left join with is null seems to be a good solution.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t1.id
    FROM  Planning AS p
    LEFT JOIN  PatientCare AS c  ON p.patient_care_id = c.id
    WHERE  p.begin >= c.begin
      AND  p.end <= c.end
      AND  c.id IS NULL;    -- to catch rows that failed the time check
```

Note:  If the time ranges can *overlap* then a variation on the begin/end clause is needed.